# Find file generated by Dart.io and getApplicationDocumentsDirectory in project

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter project in which I'm using the path_provider plugin to generate the directory where appData files should be stored.

The plugin is working in that it is generating the c directory file path properly but once the file has been written to and read from I can't see the file in my project structure to see exactly what has been written in. Is there a way to view the file that I've written to using Dart.IO?

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class AppDataService {

  Future<String> get _appDataLocalPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get appDataFile async {
    final path = await _appDataLocalPath;
    log("Path: " + path);
    return File('$path/appData.json');
  }

  Future<void> write() async {
    final file = await appDataFile;

    file.writeAsString("Test write");
    var out = await file.readAsString();
    log("Written: " + out);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the file is created in your testing device's storage, not inside your project folder. You can read the file using `dart:io`, and display that in your app, or else you need to view it in the Documents of your testing device.

**Tip**
If you are using an iOS Simulator or Android Emulator, these devices are stored on your computer, so the Documents of these devices will also be on your machine.

*e.g: A file stored on an iPhone 6S Simulator running on MacOS*

```
Users/musa/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4C133A22-3A0D-4F4B-A839-A799BD3614E9/data/Containers/Data/Application/E5B0A154-46BB-4E25-9A25-9DE0C53648D1/Library/Caches/output_dir/output.mp4
```

To get the file path, try the following:

```
final file = await appDataFile;

//Click on it when it is printed in the output window.
print("file://${file.path}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look up for the file if you provide the path for the file.

```
  var f = File("lib/Documents2/doc.txt").create(recursive: true);
```